# How to make selected area's background grey

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wanting to change the area marked in red to a grey color, I've tried a bunch of things but I'm stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Essentially I'm wanting to make the background a light grey color but not change the top bar or the navigation.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wk9a.jpg)

**Here is the code:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 hidden-xs-down bg-white sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Domestic Bills <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Analytics</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Export</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <main class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2">
      <h1>Title</h1>

      <div class="row">


          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3>
                  <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-panel-titles" aria-label="Left Align">Edit</button></a>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group">
                  <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><li class="list-group-item">Payment Times: </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8"><p class="input-list"><input name="site" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" type="text" value="Value"></p>
                    </div></div></li>

                    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><li class="list-group-item">Payment Method: </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8"><p class="input-list"><input name="site" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" type="text" value="Value"></p>
                    </div></div></li>


                    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><li class="list-group-item">Fixed Payments: </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8"><p class="input-list"><input name="site" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" type="text" value="Value"></p>
                    </div></div></li>


                    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><li class="list-group-item">Fixed Payment Amount: </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8"><p class="input-list"><input name="site" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" type="text" value="Value"></p>
                    </div></div></li>
                </ul>
              </div>            
            </div>


        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">                  
                <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
              </div>


              <ul class="list-group">
                  <li class="list-group-item">24th November 17<p class="task-edit">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                    </p><p class="task-delete">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </p><p class="task-time">10:20 AM Thur 30 Nov 2017</p></li>

                  <li class="list-group-item">24th October 17<p class="task-edit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                  </p><p class="task-delete">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                  </p><p class="task-time">11:00 AM Tue 28 Nov 2017</p></li>

                  <li class="list-group-item">24th September 17<p class="task-edit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                  </p><p class="task-delete">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                  </p><p class="task-time">01:19 PM Mon 27 Nov 2017</p></li>

                  <li class="list-group-item">24th August 17<p class="task-edit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                  </p><p class="task-delete">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                  </p><p class="task-time">03:52 PM Sat 25 Nov 2017</p></li>
                </ul>
              </div>            
            </div></div>










            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <!-- Default panel contents -->
              <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3></div>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Code</th>
              <th>2</th>
              <th>3</th>
              <th>4</th>
              <th>5</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1,001</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,002</td>
              <td>amet</td>
              <td>consectetur</td>
              <td>adipiscing</td>
              <td>elit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,003</td>
              <td>Integer</td>
              <td>nec</td>
              <td>odio</td>
              <td>Praesent</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,003</td>
              <td>libero</td>
              <td>Sed</td>
              <td>cursus</td>
              <td>ante</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,004</td>
              <td>dapibus</td>
              <td>diam</td>
              <td>Sed</td>
              <td>nisi</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,005</td>
              <td>Nulla</td>
              <td>quis</td>
              <td>sem</td>
              <td>at</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,006</td>
              <td>nibh</td>
              <td>elementum</td>
              <td>imperdiet</td>
              <td>Duis</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,007</td>
              <td>sagittis</td>
              <td>ipsum</td>
              <td>Praesent</td>
              <td>mauris</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,008</td>
              <td>Fusce</td>
              <td>nec</td>
              <td>tellus</td>
              <td>sed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,009</td>
              <td>augue</td>
              <td>semper</td>
              <td>porta</td>
              <td>Mauris</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,010</td>
              <td>massa</td>
              <td>Vestibulum</td>
              <td>lacinia</td>
              <td>arcu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,011</td>
              <td>eget</td>
              <td>nulla</td>
              <td>Class</td>
              <td>aptent</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,012</td>
              <td>taciti</td>
              <td>sociosqu</td>
              <td>ad</td>
              <td>litora</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,013</td>
              <td>torquent</td>
              <td>per</td>
              <td>conubia</td>
              <td>nostra</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,014</td>
              <td>per</td>
              <td>inceptos</td>
              <td>himenaeos</td>
              <td>Curabitur</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,015</td>
              <td>sodales</td>
              <td>ligula</td>
              <td>in</td>
              <td>libero</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

You need to to write or overwrite rules from bootsrap.

Create the selectors for each div you want to target .

example:

```
main, 
main .panel ,
main .panel .panel-heading 
/* and whatevere else you want to select */
{
  background:grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your are looking for is a background-color css property.
You can give him a color. Personaly i like #939393.

So you can try adding :
 `style="background-color:#93939;` to your `<main>` tag

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 hidden-xs-down bg-white sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Domestic Bills <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Analytics</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Export</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <main class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2" style="background-color:#939393">
      <h1>Title</h1>

      <div class="row">


          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3>
                  <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-panel-titles" aria-label="Left Align">Edit</button></a>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group">
                  <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><li class="list-group-item">Payment Times: </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8"><p class="input-list"><input name="site" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" type="text" value="Value"></p>
                    </div></div></li>

                    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><li class="list-group-item">Payment Method: </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8"><p class="input-list"><input name="site" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" type="text" value="Value"></p>
                    </div></div></li>


                    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><li class="list-group-item">Fixed Payments: </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8"><p class="input-list"><input name="site" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" type="text" value="Value"></p>
                    </div></div></li>


                    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><li class="list-group-item">Fixed Payment Amount: </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8"><p class="input-list"><input name="site" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" type="text" value="Value"></p>
                    </div></div></li>
                </ul>
              </div>            
            </div>


        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">                  
                <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
              </div>


              <ul class="list-group">
                  <li class="list-group-item">24th November 17<p class="task-edit">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                    </p><p class="task-delete">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </p><p class="task-time">10:20 AM Thur 30 Nov 2017</p></li>

                  <li class="list-group-item">24th October 17<p class="task-edit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                  </p><p class="task-delete">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                  </p><p class="task-time">11:00 AM Tue 28 Nov 2017</p></li>

                  <li class="list-group-item">24th September 17<p class="task-edit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                  </p><p class="task-delete">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                  </p><p class="task-time">01:19 PM Mon 27 Nov 2017</p></li>

                  <li class="list-group-item">24th August 17<p class="task-edit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                  </p><p class="task-delete">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                  </p><p class="task-time">03:52 PM Sat 25 Nov 2017</p></li>
                </ul>
              </div>            
            </div></div>










            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <!-- Default panel contents -->
              <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3></div>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Code</th>
              <th>2</th>
              <th>3</th>
              <th>4</th>
              <th>5</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1,001</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,002</td>
              <td>amet</td>
              <td>consectetur</td>
              <td>adipiscing</td>
              <td>elit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,003</td>
              <td>Integer</td>
              <td>nec</td>
              <td>odio</td>
              <td>Praesent</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,003</td>
              <td>libero</td>
              <td>Sed</td>
              <td>cursus</td>
              <td>ante</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,004</td>
              <td>dapibus</td>
              <td>diam</td>
              <td>Sed</td>
              <td>nisi</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,005</td>
              <td>Nulla</td>
              <td>quis</td>
              <td>sem</td>
              <td>at</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,006</td>
              <td>nibh</td>
              <td>elementum</td>
              <td>imperdiet</td>
              <td>Duis</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,007</td>
              <td>sagittis</td>
              <td>ipsum</td>
              <td>Praesent</td>
              <td>mauris</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,008</td>
              <td>Fusce</td>
              <td>nec</td>
              <td>tellus</td>
              <td>sed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,009</td>
              <td>augue</td>
              <td>semper</td>
              <td>porta</td>
              <td>Mauris</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,010</td>
              <td>massa</td>
              <td>Vestibulum</td>
              <td>lacinia</td>
              <td>arcu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,011</td>
              <td>eget</td>
              <td>nulla</td>
              <td>Class</td>
              <td>aptent</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,012</td>
              <td>taciti</td>
              <td>sociosqu</td>
              <td>ad</td>
              <td>litora</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,013</td>
              <td>torquent</td>
              <td>per</td>
              <td>conubia</td>
              <td>nostra</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,014</td>
              <td>per</td>
              <td>inceptos</td>
              <td>himenaeos</td>
              <td>Curabitur</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,015</td>
              <td>sodales</td>
              <td>ligula</td>
              <td>in</td>
              <td>libero</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a div containing them all?... I can see you are good at this, so I hope you tried to find the class name and set the background-color="someShadeOfgrey"... You can do this with the < style> tag or a CSS file :)... or just implement it with the < div> tag

```
<div class="myClass" style="background-color:grey;">
```